# Java: is there an easy way to draw an outline of a line?

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I have an existing application that draws very complex graphics (paths using straight, curved (circle & Bezier, etc. lines); I'd like for it to be able to draw the outline of those lines. (Instead of drawing a single line draw two parallel lines.) I was able to get close by drawing the lines again with a smaller width using the background color (so I get the parallel lines) but this erases everything between the two parallel lines. I want the area between the lines to be transparent so that what's underneath the lines can be seen between the two parallel lines.
Any ideas?

Comment: How about overriding `paint' of every shaped used to draw 2 lines instead of one ? I think the difficulty is to determine on which side to place the 2nd line.

Comment: I tried to solve this by creating a Stroke object with thickness, and then passing the shape that you wish to draw into the Stroke's `.createStrokedShape(myShape)` method, drawing the returned object, but this does not handle sharp corners well, and I think that any attempt that you do to solve this yourself will need to deal carefully with sharp corners. To see what I did, look at [this pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/fNUNdKy4). Not posted as an answer since it doesn't fully work.

Comment: Your method would work if you set the graphics `Paint` to a `TexturePaint` containing the background.

Comment: @teppic Close except "I want the area between the lines to be transparent so that what's underneath the lines can be seen between the two parallel lines". My 1st try just drew the lines again narrower using the background color and that "mostly worked".

Comment: `TexturePaint` will fill the second line with the source pattern. The background if you use it.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels: That's actually pretty good. Since what I'm actually drawing is railroad tracks I don't have any sharp corners (since most trains can't do that... ;-). Thanks!

Comment: @teppic: yes, and cover up the things behind it. That's not what I want.

Comment: Not if the source for the paint _is_ the image behind the first line.

Comment: @teppic: So… I take an image of what's there (old lines and all); then draw the new line (full width); and then draw (/erase) a narrower line using the saved image as the TexturePaint? Hummm… might work… Thanks. I'll try that.

Comment: It worked when I tried it. One problem I ran in to was that the erase didn't line up if there was a transform applied to the graphics context (e.g. a rotate). I could fix it by applying an inverse transform to the texture, but the result was quite slow.